# Extract Keys from list of dictionnary through function in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of dictionnaries call x.
If I want to extract the keys and push them into a new list called y :

```
y = {k for d in x for k in d.keys()}
y = {k for k in chain(*x)}
```

Now I want to do the same operation with a function. As I don't know the name of the list of dict in advance, I was thinking of using *args

```
def formatting(*args):    
    return {k for d in args for k in d.keys()}

x_list = formatting(x)
```

But doing this return AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

When I passing the real variable name in the function, it's working...

What is the correct way of passing list of dict into a function ?

Comment: `y` is not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x_list = formatting(*x)  # <-- don't forget to expand "x" into "args"
```

Otherwise `args = (x,)` rather than `args = x` like you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks this is working ! I need to investiguate on that expand story now ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use the List Comprehension in order for y become a list

```
y = [k for d in x for k in d.keys()]
```

After, the way scnerd commented here, you should expand X in Args before using it in the function. However I didn't get why you're using the *args, since even if you don't know the name of the dicts list, you could use the function name normally and have your code working with:

```
def formatting(dicts_list):    
    return [k for d in dicts_list for k in d.keys()]

x_list = formatting(x)
```

Comment: Because I have multiple list of dict to be passed in the function and each one should return a different function.